# How do I completely remove a wireless interface (and re-add it)?

Tags: fedora, kernel, wifi

I'm trying to use a new usb wireless interface (atheros ar9271) and my onboard wireless (intel 6200) is interfering with it.  The goal is for me to be able to turn the rf kill switch on (enabling wireless, that is) so that I can use the external wireless adapter, and not have the onboard wireless show up at all.  I also want to be able to re-add it later on if I need to.  Someone suggested using rmmod, but I'm unfamiliar with this, and I don't know how to identify which module the onboard wireless is using.

So to summarize: how do I identify the module (assuming this is the right way to go about this) and then remove it?  And question 2: how do I re-add that module later on so that the onboard wireless is detected again?

Running Fedora 21.  The onboard wireless is wlan0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, you can find out which driver a network interface is using with this command:

```
ls -l /sys/class/net/<interface name>/device/driver
```

You can `rmmod` that unless it is statically linked into the running kernel (not likely for a distribution kernel and a wireless driver). Watch out for any other interfaces using the same driver which will be taken down at the same time (but it's not likely in this case that you have any other interface on the system that is using the same driver). You may want/need to make sure the interface is down with `ip link set <interface name> down` before you remove its driver.

To add it again, use `modprobe` with the same driver name.

If the wireless device is a PCI device, you can [control with actions like "enable" and "remove"](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs-pci.txt) instead of removing the driver:

```
# Get rid of the device (but does not power it off)
# Might not be reversible, I'm not sure
echo 1 >/sys/class/net/<interface name>/device/remove
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I actually figured out how to remove it on my own (modprobe -r iwldvm and modprobe -r iwlwifi) immediately after posting this.

Comment: Do you know how to permanently mobprobe -r a module?  Ie, so it doesn't come back when I reboot unless I manually re-add the module?

Comment: That would be best done by [blacklisting the module](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules), not by actually removing it (with `rm`).